# Excel Generating Iterating Cell References

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to generate Excel Cell references? I have been manually iterating the below:

```
=($B$12-C12)*$B$3*C3
=($C$12-D12)*$C$3*D3
=($D$12-E12)*$D$3*E3
=($E$12-F12)*$E$3*F3
=($F$12-G12)*F$3*G3
=($G$12-H12)*$G$3*H3
=($H$12-I12)*$H$3*I3
=($I$12-J12)*$I$3*J3
=($J$12-K12)*$J$3*K3
=($K$12-L12)*$K$3*L3
=($L$12-M12)*$L$3*M3
=($M$12-N12)*$M$3*N3
=($N$12-O12)*$N$3*O3
=($O$12-P12)*$O$3*P3
=($P$12-Q12)*$P$3*Q3
=($Q$12-R12)*$Q$3*R3
=($R$12-S12)*$R$3*S3
=($S$12-T12)*$S$3*T3
=($T$12-U12)*$T$3*U3
=($U$12-V12)*$U$3*V3
=($V$12-W12)*$V$3*W3
=($W$12-X12)*$W$3*X3
=($X$12-Y12)*$X$3*Y3
=($Y$12-Z12)*$Y$3*Z3
=($Z$12-AA12)*$Z$3*AA3
..
..
..
..
..
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine nothing more boring than typing that out.  try the below, I assume you want the code to print to cells? this has a few more $ than you wanted, let me know if thats a problem.  Also, just change the countto variable to the number of iterations you want.  Hope it helps.

```
Sub poorguy()
Dim counter As Long
Dim countto As Long
Dim col1 As String
Dim col2 As String
Dim col3 As String
Dim col4 As String
Dim rngwrite As Range

counter = 0
countto = 100

For i = 0 To countto
    col1 = cells(12, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col2 = cells(12, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col3 = cells(3, 2).Offset(0, counter).Address
    col4 = cells(3, 3).Offset(0, counter).Address
    Set rngwrite = cells(1, 1).Offset(counter, 0)
    rngwrite.Value = "=(" & col1 & "-" & col2 & ")*" & col3 & "*" & col4
    counter = counter + 1
Next
Set rngwrite = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: too many $s....Your code output gives: =($B$12-$C$12)*$B$3*$C$3

Mine is: =($B$12-C12)*$B$3*C3

Answer (score 0):

Use Row to get the row number then use Offset to offset from a reference point the number of columns relative to the row number. Example:

```
=(OFFSET(A1,0,ROW(B1))-OFFSET(A1,0,ROW(B1)+1))*OFFSET(A1,0,ROW(B1))*OFFSET(A1,0,ROW(B1)+1)
```

The assumption is that your data starts in B1 and C1

Comment: do you mean the assumption is that my data starts in A1 and B1? I don't see C1 anywhere in that equation....

Comment: No, B1 and C1 and you are entering the formula in Row 1. This part is C1  `OFFSET(A1,0,ROW(B1)+1)` Offset A1 by 0 rows and Row(B1)+1 (2) columns